# Is it possible to see the browser stack recording videos from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, browserstack

Currently working in Jenkins, Is it possible to see the  Browser stack Videos [Test execution recordings] in Jenkins. I have already integrated the Jenkins with Browser stack. Do we have any option in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Through the Browserstack report you will be re-directed to Browserstack Dashboard wherein you will able to see video logs.

you can refer to this link for more information: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/jenkins